# Verify if username exists when updating username

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

In this situation, there is a form used for updating user information (username, password, mobile number,  etc.).

Below is the code I used to check if the username exists in the database:

```
string sql = "SELECT username FROM (SELECT username FROM useraccount WHERE username != @old_uname)ua WHERE BINARY username = @new_uname LIMIT 1;";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, SecurityMod.dbconn());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@old_uname", old_uname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new_uname", new_uname);

if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null)
{
    isValidNewUname = true;
}
```

It works if the user really changes his/her username. But the problem occurs when the user made changes to anything but the username field. The isValidNewUname variable remains false. Any ideas and suggestions would be a big  help.

Comment: Run two commands: check user exists, if yes then change username. Or write a query to do that. Or a stored proc.

Comment: Don't you have a user ID?

Comment: yes, I do have a user ID column in the database

Comment: Unrelated tips: `MySqlCommand` is IDisposable so should be in a `using` block. And you may like to read [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of basing on fetched username, I opted instead for the uid. I solved the problem with the following code:

```
string sql = "SELECT uid FROM useraccount WHERE BINARY username = @new_uname;";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, SecurityMod.dbconn());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new_uname", new_uname);
                if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null || cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == userID)
                {
                    isValidNewUname = true;
                }
```

This code is shorter and more simple hence easier to maintain. What happens here is that the query looks for the uid of the @new_uname in the database. It then compares the fetched uid to the uid of the current user. If it is the same, it means that the fetched result of the query is simply the user itself, so it doesn't really matter if their the same or not since it belongs to only one user. If the fetched uid is not equal to the uid of the current user, it means the username input by the user is already taken so isValidNewUname would be false. If the query above doesn't return results, then the @new_uname is available since it doesn't have a record in the database.